# Regular Expression - Matching first occurrence ONLY of every line

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am very new to RegExp.  Please help me with matching the first occurrence of every line in the data below.  I am using NotePad++.

Here is my text:

```
ShipAddressName [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/AddressName',
ShipAddressContact [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/AddressContact',
ShipAddressLine1 [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/AddressLine1',
ShipAddressLine2 [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/AddressLine2',
ShipCity [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/City',
ShipState [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/State',
ShipZipCode [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/ZipCode',
```

If I use This `('../)` in Find What, it would work. However, I would like to learn how to match ONLY the first `../` (without the single-quote), so I can replace it with `../../`

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. In one part you state you want to match the first occurrence and another part you state you want the second. Which is it?

Comment: So you just want to add an additional `../` to each path (adding it only once per line)?

Comment: mason81, I updated my question already.  Yes,  I want to add additional ../  or sometime remove ../

Comment: You could just find `'\.\./` and replace it with `'../../`, but if you really just want to match just the first occurrence without including the single-quote, you could just search for `(?<=')\.\./` and replace it with `../../`.

Comment: yes, search '(?<=')\.\./' is exactly what I am looking for.  Just for learning purpose, can you please explain (?<=').... meaning.  Thank you so much

Comment: @Milacay `(?<={pattern})` is called a positive lookbehind. It matches the pattern, but excludes it from the result.

Comment: Here is a helpful resource for lookahead and lookbehind: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html (take note that not all regex engines support them and they can be costly to use)

Comment: @Milacay I wrote up my explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is very specific to Notepad++

To ADD an extra `../` use the following find and replace patterns (with regex setting checked):

Find: `'(\.\./)`

Replace: `'$1$1`

[image: Example when entered properly in Notepad++]

To REMOVE one `../` use the following find and replace patterns (with regex setting checked):

Find: `'(\.\./)`

Replace: `'`

[image: Example when entered properly in Notepad++]

Comment: @Milacay The reason your pattern didn't work is because you have to escape dot/period `.` with a backslash \ otherwise the regex engine will treat it like a wild card, matching any character. If you're really trying to learn regex you should start with a nice resource like http://regexr.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do this by code:

```
string input = @"ShipAddressName [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/AddressName',
    ShipAddressContact [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/AddressContact',
    ShipAddressLine1 [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/AddressLine1',
    ShipAddressLine2 [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/AddressLine2',
    ShipCity [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/City',
    ShipState [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/State',
    ShipZipCode [varchar](100) '../../../ShipTo/ZipCode',";

string pattern = @"(.+?)(\.\.\/)(.+\n?)";

string replacement = @"$1$2$2$3";

Console.Log(Regex.Replace(input,
    string pattern,
    string replacement
));

// Output:
// Execution Time(sec.):
// 0.000022

// Raw Match Pattern:
// (.+?)(\.\.\/)(.+\n?)

// Raw Replace Pattern:
// $1$2$2$3

// $sourcestring after replacement:
// ShipAddressName [varchar](100) '../../../../ShipTo/AddressName',
// ShipAddressContact [varchar](100) '../../../../ShipTo/AddressContact',
// ShipAddressLine1 [varchar](100) '../../../../ShipTo/AddressLine1',
// ShipAddressLine2 [varchar](100) '../../../../ShipTo/AddressLine2',
// ShipCity [varchar](100) '../../../../ShipTo/City',
// ShipState [varchar](100) '../../../../ShipTo/State',
// ShipZipCode [varchar](100) '../../../../ShipTo/ZipCode',
```

Answer (score 2):

You could just find `'\.\./` and replace it with `'../../`, but if you really just want to match just the first occurrence without including the single-quote, you could just search for `(?<=')\.\./` and replace it with `../../`.

Here is the meaning of the pattern:

- `(?<=')` - A positive look-behind which looks for the single-quote character.  A look-behind states that only strings which are preceded by certain text are eligible as a match (but that preceding text is not considered part of a match)

  - `(?<=` - Begins a positive look-behind sub-pattern
  - `'` - The character to look for
  - `)` - Ends the look-behind sub-pattern
- `\.\./` - The text to match

  - `\.` - An escaped period (so that regex doesn't interpret the period as the any-character character-set

Alternatively, you could probably just search for `(?<='\.\./)` and replace it with `../`.  That would merely match the position, but not any of the text, so when it performs the replacement, it acts as a simple insertion.

On a side-note, there are also negative look-behinds, which indicate that the given text cannot precede a match.  There are also positive and negative look-aheads.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  That helps tremendously.